# Stored Procedure algorithm taking 9 hours- better way of doing this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to build an SQL stored procedure which basically updates an existing table (of about 150,000 rows) with an ID.

The table that this stored procedure will run over is basically a list of people, their names, addresses etc.

Now the algorithm for the id of the person is as follows:
- Take up to the first 4 characters of the persons first name.
- Take up to the first 2 characters of the persons last name.
- Pad the rest with 0's, with a counting number at the end, until the field is 8 characters.

For instance, the name JOHN SMITH would have an ID of 'JOHNSM00'. If there were 2 JOHN SMITH's, the ID of the next person would be JOHNSM01. If the persons name was FI LYNN for instance, the ID would be FILY0000.

I've got the following stored procedure that I wrote, but it takes around 9 hours to run! Is there a better way of doing this that I am missing?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LM_SP_UPDATE_PERSON_CODES]
AS

DECLARE @NAMEKEY NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @NEWNAMEKEY NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @LENGTH INT
DECLARE @KEYCOUNT INT
DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @PADDING NVARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @PERSONS CURSOR
DECLARE @FIRSTNAME NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @LASTNAME NVARCHAR(30)

SET @PADDING = '00000000'
--FIRST CLEAR OLD NEW NAMEKEYS IF ANY EXIST
UPDATE LM_T_PERSONS SET NEW_NAMEKEY = NULL
SET @PERSONS = CURSOR FOR
SELECT NAMEKEY, NAME_2, NAME_1 FROM LM_T_PERSONS

OPEN @PERSONS
FETCH NEXT FROM @PERSONS INTO @NAMEKEY, @FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --CHECK THE LENGTH OF FIRST NAME TO MAKE SURE NOTHING EXCEEDS 4
    SET @LENGTH = LEN(@FIRSTNAME)
    IF @LENGTH > 4 
        SET @LENGTH = 4

    SET @NEWNAMEKEY = SUBSTRING(@FIRSTNAME,1,@LENGTH)

    --CHECK THE LENGTH OF LAST NAME TO MAKE SURE NOTHING EXCEEDS 2
    SET @LENGTH = LEN(@LASTNAME)
    IF @LENGTH > 2
        SET @LENGTH = 2

    SET @NEWNAMEKEY = @NEWNAMEKEY + SUBSTRING(@LASTNAME,1,@LENGTH)
    SET @LENGTH = LEN(@NEWNAMEKEY)
    SET @I = 0
    SET @PADDING = SUBSTRING('00000000',1,8 - LEN(@NEWNAMEKEY) - LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@I)))
    --SEE IF THIS KEY ALREADY EXISTS
    SET @KEYCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LM_T_PERSONS WHERE NEW_NAMEKEY = @NEWNAMEKEY + @PADDING + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@I) )
    WHILE @KEYCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @I = @I+1
        SET @PADDING = SUBSTRING('00000000',1,8 - LEN(@NEWNAMEKEY) - LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@I)))
        SET @KEYCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LM_T_PERSONS WHERE NEW_NAMEKEY = @NEWNAMEKEY + @PADDING + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@I) )
    END
    UPDATE LM_T_PERSONS SET NEW_NAMEKEY = @NEWNAMEKEY + @PADDING + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@I) WHERE NAMEKEY = @NAMEKEY

    FETCH NEXT FROM @PERSONS INTO @NAMEKEY, @FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME
END
CLOSE @PERSONS
DEALLOCATE @PERSONS
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this can do it without the cursor:

```
UPDATE P
SET NAMEKEY = FIRSTNAME + LASTNAME + REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(FIRSTNAME) - LEN(LASTNAME) - LEN(I)) + I
FROM
  LM_T_PERSONS AS P JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      NAMEKEY,
      LEFT(NAME_2, 4) AS FIRSTNAME,
      LEFT(NAME_1, 2) AS LASTNAME,
      CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(NAME_2, 4), LEFT(NAME_1, 2) ORDER BY NAMEKEY)) AS I
    FROM
      LM_T_PERSONS
  ) AS DATA
  ON P.NAMEKEY = DATA.NAMEKEY
```

You can verify the query here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47365/19

Comment: Thanks for that. I ran this and it almost worked perfectly without me having to modify anything, although it created ALOT of duplicates. I had to change the partition to partition by LEFT(NAME_2,4), LEFT(NAME_1,2). Thankyou so much! 9 hours down to 4 seconds

Comment: That makes sense... I've updated my answer with that change for future viewers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any strict "you should do it XYZ way" but from similar sorts of exercises in the past:

1. If you wanted to keep with the stored proc and you have a window where you can do a task which is long (time-wise), like a weekend, and you can be sure you'll be the only operation running then setting the database to Simple recovery mode (I assume you're working on a Prod database so it is in Full recovery mode) for the duration of your work then that may speed things up (as you're not writing to the transaction log - since you're not, i.e. limited recoverability you want to make sure you're the only person doing anything). I'd take a full backup before starting work in case things get nasty
2. I don't think it's so much the stored proc but the cursor usage, substring etc as you're doing procedural code somewhere which is mainly set-based. I understand the "why" behind why these are there but an option would be to take it out and use something like [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), i.e. going with a technology option more suited to the looping or doing transformations against individual rows
3. Following on from using something more suited to procedural work...You could always write a simple .NET application or similar. Speaking from my own (limited) experience I have seen this done in the past but the mileage has tended to vary based on things like the complexity of the operation (in your case sounds simple enough in terms of transforming a UserId field), volumes and the person writing it...I would say I've never seen it go particularly well (in that we never turned around and went "that was awesome") but more like it got the job done so we'd move on to something else, taking neither good nor bad from the experience (just "average").

I think SSIS is a good way to go as you can extract these records from your DB, do the operations you need (considering SSIS supports a pretty broad variety of things you can do to data, including writing .NET code {albeit VB.NET from memory} if you have to) and then update your database.

Other kinds of ETL technologies will probably allow you to do similar things but I'm most familiar with SSIS. 150k rows wouldn't be a huge problem as it can deal with much larger volumes; from my own experience we would write SSIS packages that do nothing too special but they could do these sorts of operations over 1 million rows in about 15 mins...which I think the experts will say is still a little slow :-)

HTH a bit, Nathan

Answer (score 1):

This query will get exactly what you want, and much faster.

```
select FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       ID + replicate('0',8-len(ID)-len(cast(rankNumber as varchar)))+cast(rankNumber as varchar)
from (
        select dense_rank() over (partition by id order by rownumber) rankNumber,
        FirstName, 
        LastName,

        ID
        from (
            select  row_number() over (Order by FirstName) rownumber, 
            FirstName, 
            LastName, 
            RTRIM(cast(FirstName as char(4)))+ RTRIM(cast(LastName as char(2))) as ID
        from person
      ) A
 ) B
```

Comment: What you need to do is, use this query to update your table. Certainly you may customize it a little bit. No judge about why you need ID like this, just help you to get it. But, I can't stop telling you, this kind of surrogate ID will not help you query.

Answer (score 0):

How about avoiding to use the inner `WHILE` loop by getting the maximum sequence number suffix (`@I`) for the existing `NEW_NAMEKEY` then just add 1 if more than 0, otherwise 0 if it returns NULL.